# Config Intellj to support modules with Flex Mojos

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flexmojos

I have a large app which compiles fine with maven. However it's structure is very complicated and the source for each maven module (almost all maven modules in this app are FlexMojo ones), does not live under each pom.

So the source directory in each pom is

```
<build>
 <sourceDirectory>../../src/flex</sourceDirectory>
  ....
</build>
```

While this works fine with Maven, when I import the project as a maven project in intellj, Intellij is unable to resolve any Flex stuff. I'm worried it's because it cannot find the source under each each folder module.

Can this be changed somewhere in intellij?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Flex, but in Intellij's module settings you can define source directories as you please.